# Extract elements from dynamic list as increases or decreases in python3

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, iteration, python-3.8

Hello i have a dynamic list which increases or decreases accordingly from the extracted data from a site with BeautifulSoup

```
mylist = [a,b,c,d,.......]
```

how can i make the following fstring to be dynamic as the list increases or decreases?

```
fstr = print(f"the forecast for the week is (choose number): {nl}1. {mylist[0]}{nl}2. {mylist[1]}{nl}3. {mylist[2]}{nl}4. {mylist[3]}{nl}5. Show all week")
```

As you can see i want the elements of mylist to be seperated by \nl (new line) in the fstring and not join it to a string. Is this possible?

the Output is

```
the forecast for the week is (choose number): 
1. Tuesday 08  2022
2. Wednesday 09  2022
3. Thursday 10  2022
4. Friday 11  2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a loop for your list and put the print statement in that. Something like:

```
my_list = ["a","b","c"]
print(f"the forecast for the week is (choose number):")
for idx, word in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f"{str(idx)}. {word}")
print(f"{str(len(my_list))}. Show all week")
```

This should be dynamic for your list

Comment: Best answer also. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `list comprehension` and `enumerate()` to create the dynamic list and `join()` the elements by new line character:

```
mylist = ['Tuesday 08  2022','Wednesday 09  2022','Thursday 10  2022','Friday 11  2022']

data = '\n'.join([f"{i}. {e}" for i,e in enumerate(mylist,start=1)])

print(f"the forecast for the week is (choose number):\n{data}")
```

#### Output

```
the forecast for the week is (choose number):
1. Tuesday 08  2022
2. Wednesday 09  2022
3. Thursday 10  2022
4. Friday 11  2022
```

Comment: Best answer. Thank you very much.